# Host Key Exhange failing on AWS Transfer Family SFTP

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, sftp, cryptography

I have a customer who is unable to connect to an SFTP Server (AWS Transfer Family SFTP).

The error I am getting in my logs is:

`ERRORS KEX_FAILURE Message="no matching host key type found" Kex=ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 SourceIP=x.x.x.x`

As this is a managed service I can't edit the Host Key Algorithms. All my Googling seems to suggest editing these could fix it.

I can see my SFTPs host key is SSH-RSA:

[image]

I've connected from my local machine via SSH with debug on and see this in the logs:

```
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c

debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com

debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-nistp384-kyber-768r3-sha384-d00@openquantumsafe.org,x25519-kyber-512r3-sha256-d00@amazon.com,ecdh-nistp256-kyber-512r3-sha256-d00@openquantumsafe.org,ecdh-nistp521-kyber-1024r3-sha512-d00@openquantumsafe.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256

debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
```

I've looked around, but I'm at a loss now. Is this the customer's side whose SSH client is outdated?

It's a Java-based tool they procured, so I'm not sure I can get too much info on it.

Comment: **Yes it appears this Java app is out of date.** `ssh-rsa` _algorithm_ is no longer considered secure, so that server doesn't offer it, only the better replacements `rsa-sha2-{256,512}` (which share/reuse the `ssh-rsa` _keytype_), but the Java app doesn't allow those. If the Java app is using Jsch see if it is the no-longer-supported jcraft version (stopped at 1.55) or the now-better mwiede fork (up to 2.16).  If it's using something else you'll need to figure out what. Do you get any more info in the log, like a stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only exception I can get from them is:

javalang. Exception: Error: FtpintegrationTask - impossible to connect host[x.x.x.x] - port(22] - userxyz] - password|/opt/esop/tib/var/jboss/deploy/esop.ear/tib-
host.war/WEB-INF/task/id_rsa_xyz-1]